# function cleanup / alternatives

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have dates in column A starting with [A1] that I needed this week's nearest Tuesday matched, if not - Thursday, if not - next week's Tuesday.
The functions that I'm using:

Nearest Tue [B1] `=IF(A1+1-WEEKDAY(A1,3)<A1,(A1+1-WEEKDAY(A1,3)+7),A1+1-WEEKDAY(A1,3))`

Nearest Thu [C1] `=IF(A1+3-WEEKDAY(A1,3)<A1,(A1+3-WEEKDAY(A1,3)+7),A1+3-WEEKDAY(A1,3))`

Now, to get the nearest Tue or Thu, I compare the difference between [A1] and Tue and Thu:

[D1] `=IF(AND((B1-A1)<(C1-A1),(C1-A1)>(B1-A1)),B1,C1)`

I am tempted to replace B1/C1 with nested "IF" functions that will bloat my formula, making the file thick an slow, but I will get rid of additional B and C columns in my spreadsheet that is used by multiple people.

Could you recommend how to make it cleaner, please?

Comment: what version of Excel?

Comment: If today is Wednesday, both Tuesday and Thursday are one day away, so which is "nearest"

Comment: My Excel is on a remote workspace and is called "Excel O365", the product info reads Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13127.21062)

Comment: if today is Wed, the next possible day for this job is only the upcoming Thursday. If today was Friday, the day I need to see is next Tue.

Comment: What if it is Thursday?  The same day or the next Tuesday?

Comment: oh, good question: this Tuesday stays the same Tuesday, so does today's Thursday - still this Thursday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your clarification in the comments, to find the

- current or succeeding Tues or Thursday you can use:

  ```
  =A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1-3-2*(WEEKDAY(A1,13)<=2))
  ```

In other words,

- if the date is Wed or Thu, return the next or current Thu
- Otherwise, return the next or current Tuesday.

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, Ron. Could you please explain what's going on there? Looks like you are setting the week start as Wed and jumping to the next week, deducting .. i'm loosing it

Comment: @PavloKobzar  It is based on the basic formula that `someDate - Weekday(someDate)` will always return the preceding Saturday.  Since you want to return the **same** `T/Th` you start with the next week.  And since you want to return either a Tues or Thu depending on which day of the week it is, you change the amount being subtracted by either `3` or `5`.  Using the `13` argument simply makes that computation simpler.